# Rails validates uniqueness while updating object? - very strange

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I have some simple User Model, and form for updating password.

```
@user.update_attributes(:password=>params[:password])
```

But this didn't work, and I figured out:

```
User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."auth_token" = 'z7KU4I0IXLjiRMpdF6SOVQ' LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."password_reset_token" = 'aMOjTN0ikPUOJo2JMVoDtQ' LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('somemail@mail.ru') AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/edit_user_by_reset?reset_token=aMOjTN0ikPUOJo2JMVoDtQ
```

By 3rd select I can tell, that here is uniqueness validation failed! And that is reason for ROLLBACK.
But it doesn't make sense, of course there is such row in DB, as it is UPDATE action. What should I do? I don't want pass `:validate=>false` here.

Comment: There are at least two users with the same email address, one has id=1, the other does not.

Comment: Re-read question, it is obvious that there is such user, because it is UPDATE action, it updates some columns of existing row

Comment: I assert that User.find(1).valid? will return false.   What you consider "obvious" is incorrect.  The query is looking for *other* users (ie ones with a different id) that have the same email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update password field only, you should not use mass_assignment method `update_attributes`, you should use `update_attribute(:password, params[:user][:password])`.

There is possible error with your `params[:password]` hash: if you use `form_for @user` then you should have `params[:user][:password]` and in common `params[:user]` for other fields.

You should check if the given user is valid (did you save him to DB without validation).

Answer (score 2):

Check that your object is valid **before** you call `update_attributes`.

```
@user.valid?
```

I spent a long time trying to debug a similar issue only to find that my data was bad to start with. It had nothing to do with `update_attributes`. After modifying the culprit DB entry, my model became valid again after calling `@user.find(id)` and `update_attributes` worked as expected.